# C# WPF DataTable move empty cells to left

Tags: c#, wpf, datatable, cell

I have a DataTable and i would like to loop through the cells in a row and to move empty cells to the left, so that the cells with data in are in the columns to the right and the empty to the left.

This is because i am getting the cell before i do all of this and split it on a comma, and place the second section of the split into the cell to the right of that cell

So if i have a blank cell there, which there will be after the code, it will fill into a blank cell rather than a cell with data in

I have this code currently that doesn't seem to fully work

```
int rowcount = 0;
numberoftruncationsneeded = 0;
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    int columncount = 0;
    foreach (var col in row.ItemArray)
    {
        if (dt.Columns[columncount].Caption.Contains("Address"))
        {
            if (dt.Columns.Count > columncount + 1)
            {
                if (dt.Columns[columncount + 1].Caption.Contains("Address"))
                {
                    if (dt.Rows[rowcount].ItemArray[columncount].ToString().Length >= 32)
                    {
                        bool isblank = false;
                        int blankrow = 0;
                        foreach (DataColumn colzer in dt.Columns)
                        {
                            if (colzer.Caption.Contains("Address") && (dt.Columns.IndexOf(colzer) >= columncount))
                            {
                                if (dt.Rows[rowcount].ItemArray[dt.Columns.IndexOf(colzer)].ToString().Trim() == "")
                                {
                                    dt.Rows[rowcount][dt.Columns.IndexOf(colzer)] = dt.Rows[rowcount][dt.Columns.IndexOf(colzer) - 1].ToString();
                                    dt.Rows[rowcount][dt.Columns.IndexOf(colzer) - 1] = "";

                                }
                            }
                        }
                        bool isbad = true;
                        if (isPostCode(dt.Rows[rowcount][columncount + 1].ToString()))
                            isbad = false;
                        string firstaddress = "";
                        string secondaddress = " ";
                        while (isbad == true)
                        {
                            if (firstaddress == "")
                                firstaddress = dt.Rows[rowcount].ItemArray[columncount].ToString();
                            if (!firstaddress.Contains(",") || firstaddress == "")
                            {
                                isbad = false;
                                break;
                            }
                            int lastspace = firstaddress.LastIndexOf(",");
                            var tempsecond = firstaddress.Remove(0, lastspace + 1);
                            firstaddress = firstaddress.Substring(0, lastspace);
                            secondaddress = tempsecond + " " + secondaddress;
                            if (firstaddress.Length < 32)
                                isbad = false;
                        }
                        dt.Rows[rowcount][columncount] = firstaddress;
                        if (firstaddress.Length >= 32)
                            numberoftruncationsneeded++;
                        var temp = dt.Rows[rowcount][columncount + 1];
                        dt.Rows[rowcount][columncount + 1] = secondaddress + "" + temp;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        columncount++;
    }
    rowcount++;
}
```

Comment: " doesn't seem to fully work" what is the actual outcome?

Comment: What is the value of `rowcount`? The index of the last row or the row count?

Comment: DataRow has an overload that accepts DataColumn directly get rid of all the indexOf calls.

Comment: I think it would help if i added the rest of the code, i'll edit my question

Comment: its not working as in column 1 is meant to split into column 2 which should be blank after this code has ran, but the blank is in column 3 instead so column 2 still has data inside it

Answer (score 0):

My issue was with the column loop.

Id find a blank and move it one to the left, but then the program doesnt know its meant to move it further left

To combat this i am looping backwards rather than forwards to do this

```
if(dt.Rows[rowcount].ItemArray[columncount].ToString().Contains(","))
{
  for (int i = dt.Columns.Count - 1; i > columncount + 1; i--)
     {
       if (dt.Columns[i].Caption.Contains("Address"))
        {
          if (dt.Rows[rowcount].ItemArray[i].ToString().Trim() == "")
            {
             dt.Rows[rowcount][i] = dt.Rows[rowcount][i - 1].ToString();
             dt.Rows[rowcount][i - 1] = "";
            }
        }
     }
}

//foreach (DataColumn colzer in dt.Columns)
//{
//    if (colzer.Caption.Contains("Address") && (dt.Columns.IndexOf(colzer) >= columncount))
//    {
//        if (dt.Rows[rowcount].ItemArray[dt.Columns.IndexOf(colzer)].ToString().Trim() == "")
//        {
//            dt.Rows[rowcount][dt.Columns.IndexOf(colzer)] = dt.Rows[rowcount][dt.Columns.IndexOf(colzer) - 1].ToString();
//            dt.Rows[rowcount][dt.Columns.IndexOf(colzer) - 1] = "";
//        }
//    }
//}
```